# About counting $n$ - digit binary numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Here's the problem:

> You flip a coin $20$ times and record the ordered sequence of heads and tails. How many sequences are there in which you get heads on (at least) flip #$1$, #$4$, #$7$, and #$13$?

Here's the reasoning that could possibly solve this problem:

> In general, the number of $n$ - digit binary numbers with exactly $k$ $1$s is $C(n ,k)$.

The problem is already solved: the answer is $2^{16}$. I am wondering if the way of counting $n$-digit binary numbers above applies to the problem if we let $h = 1, t = 0$ where $h$ means heads and $t$ means tails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can apply it, but then you have to consider tons of cases, one for each number of heads that come up:

There are $20$ coins. $4$ of them must turn up heads, so the other $16$ can be anything we want. We want to sum up the number of possibilities with exactly $0$ heads, exactly $1$ head, exactly $2$ heads, and so on (e.g. the number of binary numbers with exactly $0$ one's, exactly $1$ one, ...).

This gives:

$$\binom{16}0+\binom{16}1+\binom{16}2+\dots +\binom{16}{16}$$

which is simply $2^{16}$ as you already know.

Comment: Granted the sequences are defined as above, how many sequences have the same number of heads and tails? Here we can just let $n = 20$ and $k = 10$, but we can't just let $n = 20, k = 4$ in the problem in OP. What's different between these $2$ problems where the first one seems to line up nicely with the counting rule given above?

Comment: It's the difference between *exactly* $4$ heads and *at least* $4$ heads.

Comment: Does "at least" mean there could be more than $4$ heads in the sequence, say, like $hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhht$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.